Update AlertDialog with outside state variable
I've this scenario where I've a button. When clicked on the button, I show an AlertDialog and run a for loop after that. Inside the loop, I increment the value of my x state variable. Now this x variable is being used in my AlertDialog but the updated value of x is not updated in my Dialog. Any help please?
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHome(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHome extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHome({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHome> createState() => _MyHomeState();
}

class _MyHomeState extends State<MyHome> {
  int x = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  content: Text(x.toString()),
                );
              },
            );

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
              setState(() {
                x++;
              });

              print(x);

              await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
            }
          },
          child: const Text('Click me'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


ValueListenableBuilder and ValueNotifier will help in this scenario, a costless solution.
class _MyHomeState extends State<MyHome> {
  late ValueNotifier<int> x;

  void initState() {
    x = ValueNotifier(0);
    super.initState();
  }


  void dispose() {
    x.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  content: ValueListenableBuilder(
                    valueListenable: x,
                    builder: (_, x, __) {
                      return Text(x.toString());
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            );

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
              x.value++;

              print(x.value);

              await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
            }
          },
          child: const Text('Click me'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

There is even no need to rebuild your MyHome widget after changing the value of x.

The issue arises because the AlertDialog is built once and doesn't get rebuilt after the setState is called in the main widget. The StatefulBuilder inside the dialog is only used to rebuild the dialog, but it won't get triggered automatically by the main widget's setState. We need to explicitly trigger the dialog rebuild when the state changes inside the loop.
Here’s the corrected approach that ensures the dialog updates every time x changes:
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

 void main() {
    runApp(const MyApp());
 }

 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
        home: MyHome(),
         );
      }
  }

  class MyHome extends StatefulWidget {
   const MyHome({super.key});

    @override
    State<MyHome> createState() => _MyHomeState();
   }

  class _MyHomeState extends State<MyHome> {
  int x = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
   body: Center(
    child: ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () async {
        // Show the dialog first
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return StatefulBuilder(
              builder: (context, setStateDialog) {
                // Inside the builder, you can use setStateDialog to update the dialog
                return AlertDialog(
                  content: Text(x.toString()), // Display the current value of x
                );
              },
            );
          },
        );

        // Simulate some async work with a loop
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));

          setState(() {
            x++; // Update the state of the main widget
          });

          // After updating x, trigger a rebuild of the dialog
          if (Navigator.canPop(context)) {
            Navigator.pop(context); // Close the current dialog
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return StatefulBuilder(
                  builder: (context, setStateDialog) {
                    return AlertDialog(
                      content: Text(x.toString()), // Show updated x value
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
            );
          }
        }
      },
      child: const Text('Click me'),
    ),
  ),
);
}
}

Key changes:
Closing and reopening the dialog: After each iteration in the loop, we close the current dialog and immediately show a new dialog with the updated value of x. This triggers the dialog to rebuild with the new state.
Check if the dialog can be popped: We use Navigator.canPop(context) to ensure we only attempt to pop the dialog if it's currently visible.
How it works:
The button is pressed, and the dialog is shown with the initial value of x.
Inside the loop, after x is updated, the current dialog is closed (Navigator.pop) and a new dialog is shown with the updated value of x.
The dialog will be rebuilt and show the latest value of x on each iteration.
